# Firebase cloud function deploys but doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to write a function that will send a notification when a new post is added to the database.

The function deploys successfully (it shows up in the functions dashboard) but does not console log when a new post is added, or send a notification (nothing is logged at all, including errors). The new post shows up in the database so it is definitely created.

[image]

My project uses: React Native, Firebase Realtime Database

Database structure:

```
/big-appetite-96416
    /posts
        /postid
            /description
            /heading
            /id
            /location
```

[image]

Code for function in   functions/index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(); 

exports.sendNotifications = functions.database.ref('posts/{postId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
         console.log('code is read')
         const message = {
              notification: {
                  title: 'New post',
                  body: 'You’re getting this notification because a new post has been created'
              },
    };


    admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    })
        .catch((error) => {
             console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });

});
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're observing.  Be sure to include what you see in the log.  Is the function being invoked at all?  What are you doing to invoke it?  How would we reproduce this problem on our own?

Comment: Sorry, have now updated the question as best I can, I'm not sure what's relevant to say given that it's not doing anything observable - nothing is logged at all, including errors.
I assumed the function would be invoked through something being added to the relevant part of the database, should I be doing something else to invoke it?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your database in your question, as well as a screenshot of the Cloud Function panel from the Firebase console?

Comment: Apparently you haven't deployed your Cloud Function, since we only see a Cloud Function named "helloWorld" in your Cloud Function panel. You need to deploy it, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-and-execute-makeuppercase

Comment: Oops sorry, that was something I did afterwards, I'll redeploy the one I tried before...

Comment: So what is the situation now? Did you deploy your cloud function?

Comment: You aren't returning the promise at the end of the function, so it's likely throttling CPU and network (since execution is ended) before the message is sent. Try returning the `admin.messaging().send` line.

Comment: Renaud - yes, the cloud function is deployed

Comment: Michael - did you mean like this?
return admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
    })
        .catch((error) => {
             console.log('Error sending message:', error);
    });

I deployed this code and added a post to the database, there is still nothing in the log and no notification.

Comment: @HVDiva Yes, this is what Michael means. It's worth watching the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/. PS: if you want a user to receive a notification you send him a message, you need to use `@username`